# Cognos Report where total of one column is start for another column

Tags: pivot-table, cognos-11

This is for Cognos 11.2.4
I am trying to create a report where the total for one column becomes the start of the next column.

### Category      Jan     Feb     Mar

Begin Bal      0       30      60
A             10       10      20
B             10       10      10
C             10       10      10
Ending Bal    30       60      100

The data in the table is only for Type A,B, and C. The Begin Bal for Jan is 0. For Feb the Begin Bal is the End Bal for Jan (which is Total for the month) and so on for the next months.

The data is coming from a relational model.

Any ideas on how to develop this Cognos Reports?

Tried creating crosstabs

Answer (score 0):

Welcome

Is this an incorrect representation?

```
> Begin Bal     0  30 60 
>          A    10 10 20 
>          B    10 10 10 
>          C    10 10 10  
> Ending Bal    30 60 100
```

If you have the beginning balance value as data item [Begin Bal]
and you have some metric, maybe [quantity]

You could set the aggregate property for [Begin Bal] to none
and the aggregate property for [quantity] to Total

Then create a calculation data item for the ending balance as
[Begin Bal] + [quantity]